# No HDMI audio output

Tags: audio, hdmi

I am building a multiroom audio setup. For this, I want to play music from my Raspberry Pi Zero W via HDMI to a soundbar.

The soundbar is working fine with my tv via HDMI.

If I connect the tv as screen and speaker to the raspi, sound is working if I set the configuration `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d`.

If I connect the soundbar to the raspi, it doesn't find any audio device and `tvservice -s` returns `state 0x40000 [NTSC 4:3], 720x480 @ 60.00Hz, interlaced`

After activating `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`, `tvservice -s` returns `state 0x6 [DVI CUSTOM RGB full 4:3], 640x480 @ 60.00Hz, progressive`

and `tvservice -m CEA` returns

```
Group CEA has 2 modes:
           mode 4: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
           mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive
```

If I run `speaker-test` I don't hear any sound.

After this I activated

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=4
hdmi_drive=2
```

`tvservice -s` returns now `state 0xa [HDMI CUSTOM RGB full 16:9], 1280x720 @ 60.00Hz, progressive`, but I still don't hear anything.

I tried also `hdmi_force_edid_audio=1`, but nothing changed.

I have no idea what to do next to get it running. I would be happy if someone has an idea :)